# Why am I getting an AttributeError? AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lstrip'

Tags: python, python-2.7, email, smtp, smtplib

I am trying to send an email but something is going wrong and I don't know what.
Can somebody help me?

device = raspberry pi

Python version = 2.7.16

software = raspbian

E-Mail server = gmail

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart


username = 'MyEmail@gmail.com'
password = 'MyPassword'
```

---

```
def send_mail(text ='email body', subject ='subject' ,from_email = 'My Name <MyEmail@gmail.com>', recievers =None, html =None):
        assert isinstance(recievers, list)


        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg['From'] = from_email
        msg['To'] = recievers
        msg['Subject'] = subject

        txt_part = MIMEText(text, 'tekst')
        msg.attach(txt_part)

        if html != None:
                html_part = MIMEText(html, 'html')
                msg.attach(html_part)


        msg_str = msg.as_string()

        # login to server
        print('initialising.....')
        server = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com',port=587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        print('logging in.....')
        server.login(username, password)
        
        # sending the email
        print('sending.....')
        server.sendmail(from_email, recievers, msg_str)


        server.quit()
send_mail(recievers=['MyEmail@gmail.com'])

print('done')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sending_emails.py", line 44, in <module>
    send_mail(recievers=['jorankuster2005@gmail.com'])
  File "sending_emails.py", line 28, in send_mail
    msg_str = msg.as_string()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/message.py", line 137, in as_string
    g.flatten(self, unixfrom=unixfrom)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/generator.py", line 83, in flatten
    self._write(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/generator.py", line 115, in _write
    self._write_headers(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/generator.py", line 164, in _write_headers
    v, maxlinelen=self._maxheaderlen, header_name=h).encode()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/header.py", line 410, in encode
    value = self._encode_chunks(newchunks, maxlinelen)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/header.py", line 370, in _encode_chunks
    _max_append(chunks, s, maxlinelen, extra)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/quoprimime.py", line 97, in _max_append
    L.append(s.lstrip())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lstrip'
```

I don't know what causes the error since I am not using the strip() function.

Comment: If you are only just learning the basics, you should probably ignore Python 2, and spend your time on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about these libraries, but it seems `msg['To'] = recievers` expects `recievers` to be a string, not a list. Remove the `assert` at the top, and pass in a string instead of a list to `send_mail`.